GitHub diff inconsistencies when comparing a branch with merge commit and another reverting the merge
Question
I have a git repo on GitHub (demo), which has 3 branches:

main : a default branch
branch-modify : branched by main, contains a modifying commit to main
branch-revert : branched by branch-modify, contains another commit reverting the modifying commit

On this repo, I made a PR with branch-modify against main and merged with a merged commit (#1).
Also I made another PR with branch-revert against main (#2).
I expected the second PR shows diff reverting the change by the modifying commit.
However, GitHub shows empty diff.
Why did the diff end up empty? If this is an intended behavior, what is the rational behind it?
Git graph of repo after the operations:
% git log --all --oneline --graph
*   97d2b9b (HEAD -> main, origin/main) Merge pull request #1 from nekomachi-touge/branch-modify
|\
| | * 6d23f11 (origin/branch-revert, branch-revert) Revert "modify test.txt"
| |/
| * eaec7f6 (origin/branch-modify, branch-modify) modify test.txt
|/
* c1f094b add test.txt


Prior research
I found similar questions:

git compare doesnt show any difference
Github showing an incorrect diff between main branch and PR branch

Both suggest the difference between two-dot and three-dot diffs, but I don't spot any difference in my case.
% git diff main..branch-revert
diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 55b5f1f..323fae0 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-foofoo
+foobar
% git diff main...branch-revert
diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 55b5f1f..323fae0 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-foofoo
+foobar

Also, I found the "Comparing changes" function produce diffs not converse if I compare main to branch-revert then swap the branches:
https://github.com/nekomachi-touge/github-revert-test-20240814/compare/main...branch-revert
https://github.com/nekomachi-touge/github-revert-test-20240814/compare/branch-revert...main

Background
In my work, I have an IaC repo controlling two clusters with active/standby-style redundancy.
To switch active cluster, I need to make a change in the repo.
I wanted to test the redundancy by making a PR then reverting it with another PR.
However, after merging the former PR, the diff of the latter PR became empty, which was totally unexpected.
Trying to reproduce and understand the issue led me into posting this question.

Update
(08/24/2024) The merge base between main and branch-revert is the "modify test.txt" commit:
% git merge-base main branch-revert
eaec7f69baf9c990021537ad269cb4e6527a7b37


My guess is that Github shows you the diff against c1f094b, not the diff against 97d2b9b.

Related issue discussed on GitHub Community: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/39031

The problem is that you created two simultaneous pull requests, with one dependent on the other, and the way you did it resulted in this GitHub behavior.

You branched branch-revert from branch-modify.
You then created two pull requests, one for branch-modify and one for branch-revert.
And (this is the key point) you configured your second pull request, the one for branch-revert, by asking to merge it into main. (This is an easy configuration to make, as it is the default.)

Therefore, even after you merged the first pull request, the second (branch-revert) pull request includes both the branch-modify commit and the branch-revert commit (because the merge-base between branch-revert and main is the root commit):

That is the way to look at what the pull request "consists of". Well, sure enough, the sum total of file changes over the entire course of those two commits is nil; test.txt goes from "foobar" to "foofoo" and back again to "foobar".
How else might you have done things, and what would the result have been?

Since branch-revert was branched from branch-modify, you could have created your second pull request by asking to merge into branch-modify. If you had done that, then when the first (branch-modify) pull request got merged, GitHub would have repointed the merge target for the second pull request as main, and the pull request would have consisted of just one commit, the revert commit, and the "files changed" would have included test.txt — the "correct" result.

Alternatively, you could have waited until after the first pull request was merged, before creating the second pull request. That also would have given the same "correct" result.


No major harm is done here in the long term by doing things the way you did them, because merging the second pull request will have the expected result. It's just that GitHub's display of what the second pull request "consists of" comes out in a way that has surprised you (hence your question).

Keep in mind, too, that this is entirely a matter of how GitHub displays things at its site. It has almost nothing to do with Git! Pull requests are not a Git feature. A pull request is effectively a trick performed by the hosting site, as a convenience for people doing collaborative development. (That is why looking at the Git log locally didn't help you very much. Git knows nothing of what's going on here.) Every hosting site that adds this sort of feature can do it in its own way and can display the info in its own way. In this case, you simply stumbled across a quirk of the way GitHub does things.

Thanks for answering, but is it a mistake (Git users should not do this)? In this case we can avoid this. But consider when we first introduce a hotfix changing a line then a robust fix later reverting the change. This sounds like a perfectly valid scenario.

@nekomachi-touge That's perfectly valid. You did nothing wrong. You only were surprised by the way in which Github handles the situation.

I agree, I'll modify to remove "incorrectly".

@nekomachi-touge See if you find that edit a bit more reassuring.

@j6t @matt Thank you for clarification, but I'm still confused. Since main is changed by merging branch-modify, PR #2 "consists of" the revert, hence the diff should contain something? Also, the merge base between main and branch-revert is eaec7f6, not c1f094b thus the three-dot diff contains the revert as the original question shows. Why doesn't GitHub show the diff (GitHub design decision or something else)?

I added the output of git merge-base main branch-revert to the Update section of my question for clarifying my point above.

It doesn't matter what the merge base is now. At the time you created the second PR, because you asked to merge branch-revert into main, the merge base was c1f094b. Anyway, poking around the local repo is not going to help here. As I explained in my final paragraph (small print), what GitHub does is entirely up to GitHub; pull requests are not a Git feature. And I am not here to justify what GitHub does; I'm just explaining it. I've told you how to get the "right" answer next time you have one PR branch dependent on another. That's the best that can be done in this situation.

@matt My bad, your point click with me after I realized that the merge base before PR #1 merge was c1f094b. Now I see what's going on here!
